# Looking for a character OR a sequence in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that detects multiple patterns in a text, among which a sequence of more than one space. I'm doing stuff like this:

`/[abc( {2,})]/`

But it seems to also detect the single space. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What strings do you want to match? `a`, `b`, `c` or double spaces? `[abc]| {2,}`?

Comment: any string containing either a, b, c or 2+ spaces

Comment: Parentheses and curly brackets are treated as literal characters when they appear within square brackets.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[abc( {2,})]` pattern is a character class (or bracket expression in other terminology) that matches a single char, `a`, `b`, `c`, `(`, space, `{`, `2`, `,`, `}` or `)`. You cannot define *char sequences* inside character classes.

You may use

```
[abc]| {2,}
```

Or, to match any 2 or more whitespaces, use

```
[abc]|\s{2,}
```

The `|` [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) is used to separate two alternatives here:

- `[abc]` - a character class (bracket expression) that matches a single char, either `a`, `b` or `c`
- `|` - or
- `{2,}` - two or more spaces.

**NOTE**: Whenever you want to use this alternation inside a longer pattern it is a good idea to wrap it with a [group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) so that it does not "corrupt" the overall regex:

```
([abc]| {2,})
```

Or, with a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) if you needn't access to the value captured with these patterns:

```
(?:[abc]| {2,})
```